# How to make my text view get id from my session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

I want to show session data in a text box. I use the following model to get the id and show the data in a drop-down menu. But I don't know how to get `[id_dosen]` from the session from my database. How can I do that?

This is my _dosen_model.php_:

```
public function getDosen(){
    $this->db->order_by('id_dosen','ASC');
    $dosen= $this->db->get('dosen');

    return $dosen->result_array();
}
```

This is my controller for my login:

```
public function login() {
    $user       = $_POST['user'];
    $pass       = $_POST['pass'];
    $QuerySaya  = $this->db->query(
                    "SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN mahasiswa ON user.id_user=mahasiswa.id_user LEFT JOIN dosen ON user.id_user=dosen.id_user 
                    WHERE user.username='$user' AND user.password='$pass';"     
                );
    if ($QuerySaya->num_rows() == 0) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
        $data       = $QuerySaya->row();
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_admin_ti',             $data->id_user);
        $this->session->set_userdata('username',                $data->username);
        $this->session->set_userdata('password',                $data->password);
        $this->session->set_userdata('level_user',              $data->level_user);
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_kelas',                $data->id_kelas);   
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_dosen',                $data->id_dosen);
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_mhs',                  $data->id_mhs);
        $level = $this->session->userdata('level_user');
        if ($level == 'mahasiswa') {
            $this->load->view('dashboard_mhs', $data);
        }else if($level == 'admin'){
            $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
        }else if($level == 'dosen'){
            $this->load->view('dashboard_dosen', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<select id="dosen" name="dosen" class="required form-control input-xs" placeholder="Mata Kuliah" type="text" required="required">
    <option>-Nama Dosen-</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($dosen as $a) {
            echo "<option value=".$a['id_dosen'].">".$a['nama_dosen']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: use `$this->session->userdata('id_dosen')` to get `id_dosen` wherever u want

Comment: "how to get [id_dosen] from session from my database?" typically/by default, sessions aren't stored in the database and I don't see any code here to add anything to a database table. so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but where i can place $this->session->userdata('id_dosen') to my code? @pradeep

Comment: where do you want to use your session `id_dosen`

Comment: it was done, thank you very much for ur suggest